# SharePoint 2013: Consuming query (url) filter in custom webparts

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am building webparts and self hosted apps for sharepoint 2013, I want to consume the Query String filters that the user sets up, the process should be as simple as specified here on this microsft site.

Unfortunately I dont get the option to send values to 'my web part' but I do for other stock webparts that come with sharepoint. Which leads me to believe I need to implement IFilter or equivelent in my webpart, I have found information into IFilterConsumer interface and IFilterProvider interface on msdn which seems to be exactly what I need, however the documentation has one snag:

> NOTE: This API is now obsolete

So My question is, what is Microsofts new intended way of doing this with Sharepoint 2013.

Ultimately I need to read query variables in the HostWeb request inside my AppWeb code.

Edit: Apparently IWebPartParameters is the new interface for this.... trying to implement now.

I have also tried whats suggested here: Passing parameters through sharepoint sitepage to web part Still not working, at the moment I have implemented IWebPartParameters, IWebPart, IWebPartRow and none of my functions that implement these interfaces are being called. I must be missing something in the manifest or features file maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the answer to this question is simple, firstly you can only do this in a dev environment with sharepoint installed, as you need access to the sharepoint.dll.

Then this thread answers the question http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=19791, with the following code solution which is here http://www.markitup.com/BookCodeSamples/TestingWebPartConnections.zip